# In iOS, Is there a difference between shadowColor with 0.5 alpha and shadowOpacity set to 0.5?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, shadow

Is there any difference in this:

```
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = 1
```

and this:

```
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

?

They appear to look the same, but even if they are, is there any possible performance difference?

Comment: Maybe one is animatable and the other isn't? Seems redundant.

Answer (score 2):

**They have the same visual effect and are both animatable without really any performance impact.**

The difference is that in the first example you first create a UIColor and then convert it to a CGColor.
This additional step won't really impact performance unless, for example, if you repeat this a million times.

It is in reality just a matter of preference as both accomplish the same results.

To demonstrate this you could use XCTests with one million iterations:
[image: XCTests]

And here is the code if you want to try it out:

```
let iterations = 1_000_000
    
func testPerformanceAlpha() {
    let view = UIView()

    measure {
        for _ in 0...iterations {
            view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
            view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        }
    }
}
    
func testPerformanceOpacity() {
    let view = UIView()

    measure {
        for _ in 0...iterations {
            view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        }
    }
}
```